# Keyboard Key Mapping

Tags: keyboard, wifi, bluetooth

I run a MacBook Pro 15", Wireless Bluetooth Apple Keyboard and Magic Mouse.

Everything for the last year has been working great. Just recently I FINALLY had to change my batteries in my keyboard. Upon doing so, a bunch of my key combinations from the wireless keyboard no longer work. For example:

- In IntelliJ I can press ALT + F7 to perform a certain function. This no longer works.
- In PhotoShop I used to be able to press CMD + ALT + SHIFT + S to get "save for web", this no longer works.

The basic keyboard functionality (typing/etc) works fine, its just certain key combos that do not work. If I type these EXACT same combos into the built in keyboard on my MacBook Pro, everything works fine.

How do I get my key mappings/settings to match that of my MacBook Pro keyboard? What changed and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's the deal: Keyboard is broken. Both ALT keys are broke.

Took the keyboard into the Genius bar and they verified that the keys were broken. Got a new one as it was still under warranty.